# Getting "The semaphore timeout period has expired" error on front USB 3 ports

Tags: hard-drive, usb, windows-10, motherboard, usb-3

I've recently assembled a new PC on my own! ( This is not the first time ) The config is as below.

> Processor : Intel i5 6500
>
> Motherboard : ASUS Z170 Pro Gaming
>
> RAM : 16GB DDR4

All my external devices are USB 3 and they work fine. I've this problem and it happens only on USB 3 ports on random occasions where ever I try to transfer or, write to the device ( a Hard drive ) I get the following error.

> The semaphore timeout period has expired.

I tried googling and they all suggest to switch to USB 2.0 and it all works fine! But I'm trying to transfer lot of data and it takes a hell of a time on USB 2.0. I did the following in order to ease your answers.

> Updated Motherboard drivers
>
> Updated Windows 10
>
> Tried the hard disks on other USB ports
>
> Tried back USB 3.0 and they did not report any errors such

As I mentioned I'm using Windows 10 and it's an "Education Version". If any one could identify the cause, please let me know.

Comment: do you use the USB3.1 or 3.0 ports?

Comment: I use the USB 3.0 ports! There's only one USB 3.1 Ports in this model!

Comment: do you use the Intel USB 3.0 drivers or the inbox drivers from Microsoft?

Comment: I use the USB drivers!

Comment: from? Intel or Microsoft?